# SQL Count() returns all 1s

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, duplicates, common-table-expression, microsoft-dynamics

I have been looking for the answer to this all over, but nothing I have found quite fits my problem. My underlying data comes from Microsoft Dynamics AX (the below was altered but reflects what I am working with).

The following query (SQL Server 2008, using SSMS) will return a table where there are duplicates in the "ITEMID" column, but the ITEMID/SECTIONID combination is unique. ITEMIDs can have multiple SECTIONIDs, and I want to find a count of "ITEMID".

When I add that in, it returns a count of "1" for all items, rather than "2" or more as expected.

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b2fa6/6)

I haven't been working with SQL long, so if it's something obvious, please forgive me. :)

My full query:

```
WITH cteSections AS (

   SELECT 

        i.ITEMID,
        r.SECTIONID,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY i.ITEMID, r.SECTIONID ORDER BY i.ITEMID)

    FROM InventTable i

    LEFT JOIN RetailInventItemSectionLocation r ON i.ITEMID = r.ITEMID

    LEFT JOIN InventSum s ON i.ITEMID = s.ITEMID

    WHERE s.AVAILPHYSICAL <> 0 AND r.STOREID = '00001'

)

SELECT 

    cteSections.ITEMID,
    cteSections.SECTIONID,
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT

FROM cteSections

WHERE cteSections.RN = 1

GROUP BY cteSections.ITEMID,
    cteSections.SECTIONID

ORDER BY cteSections.ITEMID
```

Expected Output:

| ITEMID | SECTIONID | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00006W | KLT27 | 1 |
| 00100 | KLT16 | 1 |
| 006101 | GCY12 | 2 |
| 006101 | GCY11 | 2 |
| 00613 | KLT16 | 1 |
| 00635 | KLT16 | 1 |
| 006815 | KLT28 | 1 |
| 006859 | GCY14 | 3 |
| 006859 | GCY15 | 3 |
| 006859 | GCY11 | 3 |

But what I get is all 1s in the "COUNT" column, no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's not enough info to say what's going on here for sure. We'd need sample data, not just a query. It looks like the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in your CTE, plus the `WHERE cteSections.RN = 1`, is eliminating all occurrences of an `ITEMID` and `SECTIONID` except for the first. When you later `GROUP BY` `ITEMID` and `SECTIONID`, there's only ever going to be one of each because of the `RN = 1`. So the count will always be 1.

Comment: The sample fiddle does the exact same thing. Also, the truncated output was indeed produced by this query (minus the "COUNT" column). I am not sure how I can provide you with more data, please make a suggestion beyond what I have posted. Should I augment the fiddle to produce all of the tables this is pulling from?

Comment: All of the rows in the fiddle are unique. None of the `ITEMID` and `SECTIONID` pairs repeat. There's no way to `GROUP BY` those two fields and get a `COUNT()` of anything but 1.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to take a look. If I go for a count of ITEMID, why does it also return 1?

Comment: It doesn't if you only `GROUP BY` the `ITEMID`: `SELECT ITEMID, COUNT(*) FROM mySampleData GROUP BY ITEMID`. Are you grouping by `ITEMID` and `SECTIONID`?

Comment: @PatrickTucci I need more than just the `ITEMID`, so if I remove `SECTIONID` from the `GROUP BY` clause, I get an error.

Comment: Then either the query or input data will need to change. `GROUP BY` works by placing rows into groups where they share the same values in the `GROUP BY` columns. If all of your `ITEMID`/`SECTIONID` pairs are unique, then each group of `ITEMID`/`SECTIONID` can only ever contain 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is that once you add a column into the `GROUP BY`, you get another row for each combination of it.

Also for some reason you are already filtering duplicates using `ROW_NUMBER`, even though the grouping would have reduced those rows anyway.

Either way, it seems you just want a windowed `COUNT`

```sql
SELECT 
    ITEMID,
    SECTIONID,
    COUNT(*) AS CountPerSectionAndItemId,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SECTIONID) AS CountOfItemIds
FROM mySampleData s
GROUP BY
  ITEMID,
  SECTIONID
ORDER BY
  SECTIONID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b2fa6/25)

Note that this count happens *after* grouping. If you want the sum of the count then you need `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY SECTIONID)`

Comment: Thanks! `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMID) AS CountOfItemIds` actually gives me the result I was after. And your code is much cleaner than mine. Marking your answer as most helpful, because it got me the closest to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I may have answered my own question following an initial discussion with @patrick tucci. The only way to get the result I want that I have been able to find is to basically "hack" the query as follows. If there is a better way to do it, please share:

```
WITH cteSections AS (

   SELECT 

        i.ITEMID,
        i.NAMEALIAS,
        r.STOREID,
        r.SECTIONID,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY i.ITEMID, r.SECTIONID ORDER BY i.ITEMID)

    FROM InventTable i

    LEFT JOIN RetailInventItemSectionLocation r ON i.ITEMID = r.ITEMID

    LEFT JOIN InventSum s ON i.ITEMID = s.ITEMID

    WHERE s.AVAILPHYSICAL <> 0 AND r.STOREID = '00001'

)

SELECT 

    cteSections.ITEMID,
    MAX(cteSections.NAMEALIAS) AS NAMEALIAS,
    MAX(cteSections.SECTIONID) AS SECTIONID,
    COUNT(cteSections.ITEMID) AS COUNT

FROM cteSections

WHERE cteSections.RN = 1

GROUP BY cteSections.ITEMID
```